# Has Iain M. Banks ever cited his inspirations for the backstory of Cheradenine Zakalwe? (possible spoilers)

Tags: inspiration, the-culture, iain-m-banks

Specifically, I recently heard the story of [Ed Gein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_Gein), and how it influenced the movie [The Texas Chainsaw Massacre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Texas_Chain_Saw_Massacre).  I'm wondering if either inspired the story of the Chairmaker.  Are there any citations of these, or other works, as influences?

Comment: This idea seems even more attractive when you bear in mind that Banks' original draft of Use of Weapons dates back to 1974 (interesting source: http://textualities.net/andrew-wilson/iain-banks-interview/ ), the same year as The Texas Chainsaw Massacre film came out.

Comment: "Cheradenine Zakalwe" by the way.

Comment: Ha!  I was scratching my head on this one, and then looked at the edit history... looks like someone tried to fix it before, but neither of us had had it right... :)

Answer (score 7):

Actually, it appears that short story "The Form of the Sword" by Jorge Luis Borges may be a direct inspiration for the background plot of the "Use of weapons". Now, I have no way to prove or disprove this, but we know for sure that Banks was quite fond of Borges' work.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Form_of_the_Sword

Comment: I can see the connection, certainly.  Do you have a citation for Banks' fondness for Borges?

Comment: 1. Multiple allusions to other works by Borges in Banks' works (this is frequently discussed elsewhere). 2. This FAQ entry: http://www.iainbanksfaq.co.uk/2008/12/who-are-iain-banks-favourite-authors.html